# Joining pivot table to access data

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I am trying to access data from a database query which I think will need a join.  I have users that can be apart of many groups.  I am using a belongsToMany
relationship.  My Models are like so

```
class User extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'users';
    protected $guarded = [];

    public function group()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Group', 'users_user_groups')->withPivot('user_id', 'group_id');
    }
}

class Group extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'user_groups';
    protected $guarded = [];
    use SoftDeletes;

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\User', 'users_user_groups')->withPivot('user_id', 'group_id');
    }
}
```

When I run everything I need too, I might get data like the following.

```
users
+----+---------------+
| id | name          | 
+----+---------------+
| 1  | John Doe      |    
+----+---------------+

user_groups
+----+---------------+-----------------+
| id | name          | description     | 
+----+---------------+-----------------+
| 1  | Group AA      | Something       |    
+----+---------------+-----------------+
| 2  | Group BB      | Something       |    
+----+---------------+-----------------+

users_user_groups
+----+---------------+-----------------+
| id | user_id       | group_id        | 
+----+---------------+-----------------+
| 1  | 1             | 1               |    
+----+---------------+-----------------+
| 2  | 1             | 2               |    
+----+---------------+-----------------+
```

So I know user with the id 1 belongs to the user_groups with ids of 1 and 2.  What I am trying to do is grab all the users within my database who
belong to a user_group with the name admin.  So I am trying something like this

```
DB::table('users')->select('userName')
    ->join('user_groups', 'users_user_groups')
    ->where('name', '=',  'admin')->get();
```

This I know is all wrong, how can I get all users within a group when using belongsToMany and a pivot table?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eloquent uses relations, not the query builder.

You can achieve what you're aiming for by doing something like this:

```
$group = Group::where('name', 'admin')->first();
$users = $group->users; // Where users is the name of your relationship (At the moment you have user)
```

Under the hood that will do two SQL statements and map them together in eloquent objects, rather than a join. The statements will look something like this:

```
select * from user_groups where name = ? and deleted_at is not null limit 1
select * from users where id in (?, ?)
```

When you have an instance `Group` you execute the relationship by calling it as if it was a property. So after that `$users` will contain a collection of `User` instances, so you can just loop through them:

```
foreach ($users as $user) {
    // Do something with $user
}
```